# How do I get the UID of the new list item I just added to Firebase using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am adding new children to a Firebase list and unique IDs are automatically created.  I need some way to get the ID thats been created so I can immediately change the URL location path to a route containing that ID.  Here is how I am creating the list items:

```
.controller('NewTestCtrl', ['$scope', 'syncData', '$location', function($scope, syncData, $location) {
  $scope.newTitle = null;
  $scope.tests = syncData('tests');
  $scope.createTest = function() {
     var newDate = new Date();
     if( $scope.newTitle ) {
        $scope.tests.$add({
           title: $scope.newTitle,
           createdDate: newDate,
           modified: newDate,
           user: $scope.auth.user.uid
        });

        $location.path("/test/" + [FIREBASE UNIQUE ID] + "/1");
     }
  };
}])
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The angularFire $add method returns a promise, which when resolved will contain a Firebase reference to your newly pushed value. With that value, you can get the UID.

```
$scope.tests.$add({
  ...your object....
})
  .then(function(ref) { 
    $location.path("/test/"+ref.name()); 
  });
```

Comment: Thank you! I am not able to try it yet, but this looks like exactly what I need.

Comment: It works! Thanks again.  Where is the documentation for this?  I've found that the documentation is a bit light/non existant/hard to find for some of the firebase features.

Comment: Glad to hear it. I've been poking around the angularfire code on github + the firebase documentation itself.