# When iterating through a list of items in AngularFire, how do I get the ID of each item?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Controller:

```
...

$scope.items = ItemService; // This is injected correctly, no problem here.

...
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <a ng-href="#/items/{{ item.id }}">{{ item.name }}</a>
</div>
```

My issue is... if I add items using `.$add()` (Firebase's `.push()`), I don't know how to get the auto-generated ID...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can iterate over `(key, value)`, which does the trick:

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="(id, item) in items">
  <a ng-href="#/items/{{ id }}">{{ item.name }}</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to iterating over key/value, each record in $firebase (assuming it's not a primitive value) will have the key attached as `$id`:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <a ng-href="#/items/{{ item.$id }}">{{ item.name }}</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the answer I **hoped** existed -- just tried it though and I don't see anything coming back for the `$id` property :(

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21996544/975669

the answer:

The angularFire $add method returns a promise, which when resolved will contain a Firebase reference to your newly pushed value. With that value, you can get the UID.

```
$scope.tests.$add({
  ...your object....
}).then(function(ref) { 

    //this is your id
    var id = ref.name(); 
  });
```

Comment: Will this still work even if I'm just *retrieving* objects? (that is, not creating a new one at the time, just reading existing ones)

Comment: No, this is only to read the response from the server when you add a new object. Firebase responds with the id of the new list item.